# can i test that a css class is added by a simulated event using Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

i have created a pretty simple wrapper for the [drop library](http://github.hubspot.com/drop/) using react, 
and i am trying to test it using [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme).

the drop library basically uses "drop target" and "drop content" elements, such that when certain mouse events happen to the "target", that it displays the "content". it does this by adding a css class to the target which is used with the css transition mechanism to display the content.

so... what i was trying to test is that when some mouse event happens that some css class is added to some element.

here is the component itself:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Drop from 'tether-drop'
import _ from 'lodash'
import 'tether-drop/dist/css/drop-theme-arrows.css'

export default class extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.drop = new Drop(
      _.extend(
        {
          target: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.dropTarget),
          content: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.dropContent),
          classes: 'drop-theme-arrows',
          position: 'right middle',
          openOn: 'hover',
          constrainToScrollParent: false
        },
        this.props.opts
      )
    )
  }

  render() {
    const target = React.cloneElement(this.props.children[0], {ref: (c) => this.dropTarget = c})
    const content = React.cloneElement(this.props.children[1], {ref: (c) => this.dropContent = c})

    return (
      <div>
        {target}
        {content}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

here is the test (using mocha, chai and enzyme):

```
import {expect} from 'chai'
import React from 'react'
import {mount} from 'enzyme'
import Drop from '../src'

describe('Drop', () => {
  let wrapper = null

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <Drop>
        <div>target</div>
        <div>content</div>
      </Drop>
    )
  })

  it('should kinda work', () => {
    const dropTargetWrapper = wrapper.find('.drop-target')
    expect(dropTargetWrapper).to.have.length(1)
    expect(dropTargetWrapper.hasClass('drop-target')).to.equal(true)
    dropTargetWrapper.simulate('mouseover')
    expect(dropTargetWrapper.hasClass('drop-enabled')).to.equal(true)
  })

})
```

the last `expect` statement is `false` tho in that the expected important class (`drop-enabled`) isn't showing up on the "drop target".

the entire github repo can be found [here](https://github.com/tony-kerz/react-drop-wrapper/tree/0b05cfa798bccc341b6d0d6b2797c505fb48bdf2) for reference

can anyone provide any guidance on how to approach this test correctly using enzyme?